Did John Hughes create Tia to be a bit like her mother Cindy?
In the movie 'Uncle Buck', did John Hughes create daughter Tia to be a bit like her mother, Cindy?
On a first viewing, one may see Tia simply as a rebellious teenager. But upon further review, she may have been a bit of a loner. She was much older than her siblings Miles and Maizy. And she seemed like she was determined to blaze her own trail, seek her own independence, and therefore hang out with her boyfriend, Bug.
While we don't know precisely why the Russells chose to settle in Chicago, the fact is that Cindy agreed to live far away from her parents who lived in Indianapolis. And I'm wondering if Cindy, like Tia, agreed to settle far away from home to gain her "independence".
Also - It's indisputable: At the beginning of the movie, Cindy and Tia both equally and fervently detested Uncle Buck's eccentric habits. It seemed like neither even gave Buck a chance.
